# Angularjs constant link post https auto convert to port 443

Tags: angularjs, cordova, https, ionic-framework

I have write a embed angularjs web in another system run in iframe.
Problem is those website force everything request through https.

So i have to make https request.
i noticed in angulajs when i declare a Constants string url exp:

```
angular.module('app.core')
    .constant("AppConstants", {
          "serverUrl": "https://example.com/web/rest/",
          "imgUrl":'https://example.com/web/file/get?fileName=',
    }
);
```

when use in Module:

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: AppConstants.serverUrl + 'getMessage',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            data: data
          };
return $http(req);
```

i watch debug it convert from: https://example.com/web/rest/ to http://example.com:443/web/rest/

So i can not request from my iframe because it don't recognize http://example.com:443 is https request, it throw error:

```
ionic.bundle.min.js:117 Mixed Content: 
The page at 'example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://example.com:443/web/rest/getMessage'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Please help me solve this case!

Comment: Can you check in your debogguer if when you try to request your server, you don't have a redirect to the `http://example.com.443` which angular is following ? And can you try your code in the same domain to see if it's related to CORS.

Comment: i see the tomcat config hava a config to redirect port like this: <Connector port="80"  address="103.27.237.41" connectionTimeout="20000"                redirectPort="443", but when hit in browser when type https, it's just https , can you give some advance ?